# Xcode: Internal error occurred while creating dependency graph

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just started getting this error today, seemingly out of nowhere. Any one see this before and know what causes it.

```
Internal error occurred while creating dependency graph: *** -[NSCFArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object at objects[10]
```

This happens when I try to build with "iPhone Device 3.x" selected. However, if I select "iPhone Simulator 3.x", everything is fine.

I am using Xcode 3.2.1.

Comment: How does the content of the objects array get created? I'm wondering if there might be a dependency on something like an external document that could be different on the device than in the file system on the simulator. That could account for one or more entries being nil in the array, which would trigger the error you described.

Comment: The catch is that this is a build-time error and I have no idea what array the error is referring to. In fact, even if I comment all uses of initWithObjects I still get the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem and it was quite simple.

1. Quit Xcode
2. Reopen Xcode
3. Open your project
4. Clean All Targets

Now everything works fine although I wish I knew how I got into that state.

Comment: What it looks like is that there is stale build information data that Xcode is trying to load before it runs the dependency graph to figure out whether it needs to be updated.  This can happen across Xcode beta releases; deleting your build folder when moving from one version of Xcode to another is sometimes helpful, usually when you've been installing new SDKs.

Comment: This makes sense and I did upgrade to XCode 3.2.1 recently but I am pretty sure that this was not the first time I attempted to build for the device since the upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

You have an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` into which you are trying to insert a `nil` or uninitialized object. As the documentation for these two arrays indicates, this is not allowed.

You need to troubleshoot where you are inserting values into an array (presumably `objects`) and find out where that `nil` value is coming from.